# R function to round a value based on decimal places of another value?

Tags: r

I have two values produced from a linear regression

```
slope = 2.005455

er_slope = 0.01588526
```

I would like to round the slope value according to the number of decimal places in er_slope. I know the round function allows for this

```
round(slope, 2)
2.01
```

However, I don't want to input the value 2. I wish to use a function which does this automatically based on any er_slope decimal places (in case the value changes in the future).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to return number of decimal places in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173692/how-to-return-number-of-decimal-places-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything until `"."` and count number of characters which can be used in `round` for `er_slope`.

```
slope = 2.005455
er_slope = 0.01588526

nd <- nchar(sub('.*\\.', '', slope))
round(er_slope, nd)
#[1] 0.015885
```