# R increase the right-most digit by 1

Tags: r, numeric

Let's say I have this vector:

```
x <- c(0, 9, 352, 0.0523, 0.00006234, -12345, -1)
```

And I would like to increase the right-most digit by 1 regardless of the sign (+/-) of the number, how should I do it?

This is my desired output.

```
x_out <- c(1, 10, 353, 0.0524, 0.00006235, -12346, -2)
```

Comment: How should it work in an edge case like `359`?

Comment: @harre As shown in the example of `9`, it should return `10`. So in your example it should return `360`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function to compute the number of decimals (taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173692/how-to-return-number-of-decimal-places-in-r)), and then do:

```r
x + ifelse(x >= 0, 1, -1)*10^(-sapply(x, dec))

#[1]      1.00000000     10.00000000    353.00000000      0.05240000
#[5]      0.00006235 -12346.00000000     -2.00000000
```

With

```r
dec <- function(x) {
  if ((x %% 1) != 0) {
    nchar(strsplit(sub('0+$', '', as.character(x)), ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][[2]])
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: For 0.00006234, your function returns 0.00006244 instead of 0.00006235 on my side, but for other numbers they are all good

Comment: Weird. I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: "Last digit" isn't super well-defined for non-integers due to [floating point precision issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). Different systems will perform differently even in the `as.character` conversion.

Comment: @Maël It works fine after removing one decimal zero, maybe it's the limitation of computer arithmetic on floating point number on my system pointed out by Gregor Thomas

Comment: I was going to suggest either `biginteger` or `Rmprf` to address the floating point, but find they're not currently available for `R-4.2.1`, so can't test.